# class concept SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, class, sapui5

I have many views which controllers alsmost have the same functions. What I want is to have a mother controller or class or whatever, which have all this function abstract or with implementation. The view controller will then inherit or extend this mother controller. I want to be sure that even if I dont explicitly implement the function in the view controller the following code will still work.

```
content.onMove(); // Content is the controller of the view
```

and I will not get this kind of error "could not find onMove()"

I dont have any start point

Thank  you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAPUI5 use require.js principles :

```
sap.ui.define([
   "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (Controller) {
   "use strict";
   return Controller.extend("", {
   });
});
```

So you can have a look to the require.js documentation to know more about class structuration.

I think you will can't have asbract because it do not exist in JS but you can overwrite very easily the function.

For example you will have a base controller like that :

```
     sap.ui.define([
           "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
        ], function (Controller) {
           "use strict";
           return Controller.extend("sap.mydemo.baseController", {
                 onShowHello : function () {
                  alert("Hello World");
                 },
                 onShowGoodBye : function () {
                  alert("Goodbye World");
                 }
           });
        });
```

and just call it on your own controller :

```
ap.ui.define([
           "sap/mydemo/baseController"
        ], function (Controller) {
           "use strict";
           return Controller.extend("", {
                 SayHelloAndGoodBye: function(){
                       Controller.SayHello();
                       Controller.SayGoodBye();
                 }
           });
        });
```

This should work.